# Get the actual length of a dynamically created hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a partially hidden div element which displays only 180 characters and  hides rest of the content of the div.

when user click on 'viewmore..' hyper in the partially hidden div,entire contents gets displayed to user and a 'showless...' hyperlink is displayed to bring it back to the initial state.

Below is the final structure of the html.Hide and show is controlled using java script.

Div 'shortcontent' displays 180 characters on UI and 'allcontent' is a hidden div which holds the remaining characters. 'morelink' is a hyperlink used to make the hidden div 'allcontent' visible to user.

```
var html = '<div class="shortcontent" id="shortcontent">' + c +
                '</div><div class="allcontent" id="allcontent">' + content +
                             //view more hyperlink
                '</div><span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="morelink">' + config.moreText + '</a></span>';

            $this.html(html);
            $this.find(".allcontent").hide(); // Hide all text
            $('.shortcontent p:last', $this).css('margin-bottom', 0);
```

I want to get the actual height of hidden div 'allcontent' after user clicks on 'view more..' hyper link.I tried the below code,but it gives height as 364px instead of 1850px which is expected.

I believe height is taken much before the click operation gets completed.

how do i wait until 'allcontent' container is fully expanded before taking the width in the below onclick event?

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'a', function () {            
         var explore = $('.allcontent').outerHeight( true );
         //How to wait until click operation is fully done here?????
});
```

I have created a fiddle so that experts can visualize my problem statement

https://jsfiddle.net/sonashetty/nca7grfp/3/

Comment: Any chance you could click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] - also please let us know WHY you need the actual height

Comment: Where is the show() method?

Comment: created fiddle as you suggested https://jsfiddle.net/sonashetty/nca7grfp/3/

Answer (score 0):

this comes directly from [this link](http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-get-real-height-of-hidden-or-overflow-hidden-elements) and it seems like a good workaround:

```
var element = $('selector');
var saved = element.css(['top', 'overflow', 'height']);
element.css({
  top : 0,
  height : 0,
  overflow : 'scroll'
});
var actualHeight = element.prop('scrollHeight');
element.css('top', saved);
```

as you can see, the `actualHeight` will contain the real height, and then return the element to its original CSS.

Comment: This solution is not working .I have created a fiddle for this...https://jsfiddle.net/sonashetty/nca7grfp/3/  ...Can you please help me out in finding a solution